# How to get a link to display a site in desktop browser but mobile view only?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I know that I can display any site in mobile view for example with Chrome I can press on F12 and select the desired device but I need to send the site link in this view to someone else , someone dont know these information to open developer tools or resize the browser so is there a way to do that ? to display a site only in mobile view ?

Comment: Let them open it on a mobile device. Other than that, do it yourself, as in, use something like TeamViewer to connect to the pc, and set everything up.

Comment: One other option I can think of, is to download a portable version of a browser, set it up with the url configured to open once the browser start, and send that entire package.

Comment: Ask them to install this chrome extension offered by google : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg : With just few clicks anyone can change the display of site easily